# Res functions not working after post request fetch (html built in function)

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, ejs, fetch-api

I have this node.js code where I process a post request sent from fetch (ejs)

```js
app.post('/signup', jsonParser, async function(req, res) {
  
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  console.log(`hello`)
  
   auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(async userCredentials => {

    const user = userCredentials.user
    console.log(user.email)
    await db.collection("users").add({
      createdAt: Date.now(),
      name: req.body.name,
      email: email,
      signupmethod: "email",
    })
      .then((docRef) => {
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
      });
      res.redirect(`/dashboard`)

  }).catch(error => {
    res.render('signup', {error:error.message})
    return console.log(error.message)

  })


});
```

Res.render and res.redirect are not working for some reason.

Here is the post request code

```html
    const data = {
        email: email,
        password: password,
        name:name,
    }
    fetch("/signup", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
})
```

When I submit the form, the post request sends, and the user is logged in, but nothing happens after that.

Why can't I redirect when the code is successful or render a page when there is an error? is there a problem with res?

Comment: not sure what you want to do but test out first by removing the 1st res.redirect : res.redirect(307, '/dashboard'); and see what happen.

Comment: @Phil Sorry that was just a mistake while pasting my code here, I didn't actually have that in my main code

Comment: @ShueiYang same thing above

Comment: Nothing happened even without that

Comment: Responding to AJAX requests with redirects is never a good idea